# Microchip Studio CodeVision Avr cant open file .hex .rom .obj

Tags: embedded, avr, atmelstudio, codevisionavr

/*Hello I have a problem about Microchip Studio CodeVision Avr.I am copied some project from network of company.I made a mistake.When i opened a project from network i compile and build it.Therefore i copied example a project to my desktop but i get some errors from CodeVision AVR.These are errors is here.How can i solve it please help me?

**Note:I use Atmel Studio 7.0 and CodeVision AVR**

**1)Can't open file C:\Users\haydar.gungor\Desktop\Proje\4.2\Debug\Exe\LTOP111.hex**

**2)Can't open file C:\Users\haydar.gungor\Desktop\Proje\4.2\Debug\Exe\LTOP111.rom**

If change some control and several things(I dont know :)) give an new error.
<1)Can't open file C:\Users\haydar.gungor\Desktop\Proje\4.2\Debug\Exe\LTOP111.obj >

I don't know how can i solve this problem.Can you Help me?
I uninstalled codevision avr and atmel studio but there is not solution
I allowed permission of folders There is no solution
Old copies can build on compiler.

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible, and avoidt telling us you "tried some things" if you cannot say what they are - they is not useful information.  Steps to reproduce.  For example you perhaps "_open codevision, load the project, build the project, get error_" then report the error _and_ the build log.  That is where and when do you get this error and what steps do you take to reproduce it. Context is everything and you have provided none.

Comment: Didn't you ask this same question a few days ago under a different user name? What happened to that?

Comment: My question deleted.Therefore I asked again.I could'nt solve it but I noticed that I build project on network.How I can solve this problem I don't know.

Comment: It was deleted for reasons of deficiency.  You have simply repeated the same deficiencies in this one.  Insufficient information, and largely about your ability to _use_ software and not how to _write_ software.  Fix the question as suggested.

Comment: @Clifford Ok All rights.When i write english comment  can make mistake.I apologized.

Comment: @Clifford Ok All rights.When i write english comment  can make mistake.I apologized.    I am working on a company.The company produce turnstile.I started 2 month ago.Old Engineers groups prefer Microchip Atmel microcontroller and CodeVision Avr compiler.My responsible if occure a mistake when turnstile work,I solve this problem.Old softwares was written on microcip studio and than compiled from codevision avr and all of software in common network.                                                                                                        My problem is here.I made a mistake.

Comment: When I work,I copied old sofware to my desktop and then i upgraded them then load common network.My mistake is here.I must compile and upgrade my softwares on desktop,I compiled them on common network.At now,If i compile it,codevision give two errors.Errors are above.

Comment: My point is (and made on your previous question) is that those are not _compiler_ or _linker_ error messages, it is specific to whatever your IDE is doing.  None of the files would exist until after a successful build, and you have given no information on wether the build was successful.  Did you event do a build?

Comment: Project dont give an error when compile it from project tab.I cant build or build all because of errors.For example old files could be builded.But new copies are cant build

Comment: Then the problem is not lack of rom, hex or obj files, it is the inability to build.